# Storing MySQL credentials in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, security, encryption

This is a similar question to "[Storing MS SQL Server credentials in a MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438009/storing-ms-sql-server-credentials-in-a-mysql-database)"

So, in theory, imagine I have 1 MySQL server. I have a "master" database, and then X number of other generic databases. What im looking for, is a way of using an app (for arguments sake, lets say a web app, running on php) to first access the master database. This database then needs to tell the app which database to connect to - in the process, giving it all the credentials and username etc.

How is the best way around this?

The three ideas I have so far

- Store the credentials in the master database for all the other databases. These credentials would of course be encrypted in some way, AES probably. The app would get the encrypted credentials, decrypt, connect.
- Store the credentials elsewhere - maybe a completely separate server. When the master database is accessed, it returns some sort of token, which can be used to access the credential storage. Again, encrypted via AES.
- Using some sort of system that I am not aware of to do exactly this.
- Not doing this at all, and come up with a completely different approach.

To give a little example. "master" would contain a list of clients. Each client would contain it's own separate database, with it's own permissions etc.

Comment: It might just be my perception, but I think you may need to clarify what you mean by credentials. Are you talking about storing MySQL database user accounts in a master schema, or client _application user_ accounts? (i.e users you manage or users your clients should, ideally, manage?)

Comment: I'm mainly confused because if you were talking about database user accounts, I can't see why you would need any permissions specified in the "master" database; those should be managed by the database itself. The original question you referenced seems to bear little relevance.

Comment: Sorry, maybe this is me over-explaining it. I am talking about mysql connection details. E.g. host, username, password and database name. These would be stored in the master database. The app would always connect to the same master database - but would then connect to a different database based on the details retreived from the master.

Comment: Are the non-master databases hosted on the same server as the master?

Comment: In this hypothetical situation, yes, but I suppose the master database could simply store the host and the app then connects to a different host. That's not my intention though.

Comment: Makes more sense to me now.

Comment: I could just use the same user to access all databases, then master doesn't have to store username and passwords. This sounds like a poor compromise. Maybe this needs more thought.

Answer (score 2):

I've had no reason to do this kind of thing myself but your first two ideas sound good to me and (as long as you include server address) not even necessarily separate ideas (could have some clients on the server with master, and some elsewhere) the client logic won't need to care. The only issue I can see is keeping the data in the "master" schema synced with the server's security data. Also, I wouldn't bother keeping database permissions in the master schema as I would think all clients have the same permissions, just specific to their schema. If you have "permissions" (settings) that limit what specific clients can do (perhaps limited by contract/features paid for), I would think it would be much easier to keep those in that clients' schema but where their db user cannot change data.

Edit: It is a decent idea to have separate database users in this kind of situation; it will let you worry less about queries from one user's client inadvertently (or perhaps maliciously) modifying another's (client account should only have permissions to access their own schema.) It would probably be a good idea to keep the code for the "master" coordination (and connection) somewhat segregated from the client code base to prevent accidental leaking of access to that database into the client code; even if encrypted you probably don't want them to even have any more access than necessary to your client connection info.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this not long ago.  It sounds like you're trying to build some kind of one-database-per-tenant multi-tenant system.

Storing encrypted credentials in a directory database is fine, since there's really no fundamentally different way to do it.  At some point, you need to worry about storing some secret (your encryption key) no matter what you do.

In my use case, I was able to get away with a setup where the directory just mapped tenants to db-hosts.  The database name and credentials for each tenant were derived from the tenant's identifier (a string).  So something like, given a TenantID `T`:

host = whatever the directory says.
dbname = "db_" + `T`
dbuser = `T`
dbpass = sha1("some secret string" + `T`)

From a security standpoint, this is no better (actually a bit worse) than storing AES encrypted credentials in the directory database, since if someone owns your app server, they can learn everything either way.  But it's pretty good, and easy to implement.

This is also nice because you can think about extending the idea a bit and get rid of the directory server entirely and write some function that maps your tenant-id to one of N database hosts.  That works great until you add or remove db servers, and then you need to handle shuffling things around.  See how memcache works, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) to do this in much systematic way. In fact this is a strong use-case for this.

Percona has already written a great [blog](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/11/14/using-vault-mysql/) on it,